# One or many argument in Scala

Tags: java, scala, java-8

I´m porting a code from Java to Scala and I´m having problems when other Java classes consumes that ported code.

In Java I had

```
 private void logInfo(Marker marker, Object message, MessageFormatMessage template, Object... objects)
```

where the method can receive one or many objects `Object... objects`

In Scala the code it´s ported as

```
  private def logInfo(marker: Marker, message: Any, template: MessageFormatMessage, objects: Any*): Unit = {
```

Where I use the one or many objects as `Any*`

But from Java code it´s cannot be used as it was used before.

Any idea how to do this porting and continue being retro compatible?

Regards.

Comment: You have to tag the method with [`@varargs`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/varargs.html) to make it compatible with **Java**. - More info can be found [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-annotate-varargs-methods-in-scala-annotation).

Comment: wow very nice, I did not know about this tag thanks!!!!